# PHP AJAX Confirm on Form Submit

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, validation

I have a small form which contains a first name, last name and a date.  On clicking to submit the form I want it to check the database for a duplicate entry (with Ajax), and if there is already 1+ entries, present a confirm window confirming another submission.  The confirm shouldn't show if there aren't any entries.

For some reason it seems to be presenting the confirm without the result from the Ajax PHP page.  If I introduce an alert after the `xmlHttp.send(null)` line, it gets the text from the PHP (as wanted), making me think I misunderstand the order the code is executed.  Here is the code:

Javascript:

```
    function check_duplicates() {
        var first = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
        var last = document.getElementById('last_name').value;
        var date = document.getElementById('event_date').value;

        var xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
        if (xmlHttp == null) {
            alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
            return;
        }

        var result = "ERROR - Ajax did not load properly";
        var url="check_duplicate.php";
        url=url+"?first="+first;
        url=url+"&last="+last;
        url=url+"&date="+date;

        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if(xmlHttp.readyState==4) {
                result = xmlHttp.responseText;
                alert("RESULT="+result);
                if(result != "clean") {
                    var validate = confirm(result);
                    return validate;
                }
            }
        }

        xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
        var test = xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    function GetXmlHttpObject() {
        var xmlHttp = null;
        try {
            // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
            xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch (e) {
                // Internet Explorer
                try {
                    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (e) {
                    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
        }

        return xmlHttp;
    }
```

PHP:

```
// DATABASE CONNECTION INFORMATION REMOVED

$first = $_GET['first'];
$last = $_GET['last'];
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_GET['date']));

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM Table WHERE First='$first' AND ".
        "Last='$last' AND Date='$date'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($row['count'] > 0) {
   if($row['count'] == 1) {
      echo "There is already an entry for ".$first." ".$last." on ".
           date('M jS',strtotime($date)).".\n".
           "Are you sure you want to submit this entry?";
   }
   else { // plural version of the same message
      echo "There are already ".$row['count']." entries for ".$first." ".
        $last." on ".date('M jS',strtotime($date)).".\n".
       "Are you sure you want to submit this entry?";
   }
} else {
   echo "clean";
}
```

Comment: Does it alert "RESULT= ERROR - Ajax did not load properly"?

Comment: No, it alerts "RESULT= ", but as I said, if I put a simple alert after `var test = xmlHttp.send(null);` it then alerts with the proper output (from the PHP).  That's what's got me confused about delay/order of the function calls.

Comment: ah, but you see you have already set the value of result to be "ERROR - Ajax did not load properly", which is being overwritten to become blank. your php is returning a blank somewhere. I cannot see where, though.

Comment: I don't think the PHP is being hit at all.  I have edited it to read just `die("PHP page hit");` and it still won't trigger unless I have some delay after the `send()` call.  I'm not sure what's causing it...

Comment: So if you check after a delay you get "PHP page hit"? This is very curious.

Comment: I agree that your results are suspicious.  What browser are you using? Within your `onreadystatechange` handler, try using `this` instead of `xmlHttp`.  Also, using the synchronous code might give you different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer using synchronous AJAX.  This way, you don't have to overload the default form handling to get it to work.  However, **all javascript will be blocked** while the confirmation request is running, which means your web page may appear to come to a screeching halt for however long the confirmation request lasts.

This function will return true if the record should be added, and false otherwise.

```
function check_duplicates() {
    var first = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
    var last = document.getElementById('last_name').value;
    var date = document.getElementById('event_date').value;

    var xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlHttp == null) {
        alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
        return false;
    }

    var result = "ERROR - Ajax did not load properly";
    var url="check_duplicate.php";
    url=url+"?first="+encodeURIComponent(first);
    url=url+"&last="+encodeURIComponent(last);
    url=url+"&date="+encodeURIComponent(date);

    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,false);
    xmlHttp.send(null);

    var validated = true;
    var result = xmlHttp.responseText;

    if (result != 'clean')
        validated = confirm("RESULT="+result);

    return validated;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code return `undefined`.

```
 var test = xmlHttp.send(null);
```

What you have to understand is that the `send()` call returns immediately and Javascript keeps running.  Meanwhile, your AJAX request is running in the background.  Also, your `onreadystatechange` handler is called once the request is done, whether it takes 10ms or 100s, and its return value is not received by the rest of your code.

I think what you wanted to submit the form AFTER the confirmation was finished.  You only know when the request is finished from inside your `onreadystatechange` handler.  The problem here is that, in order to wait for the AJAX request to finish you have to override the default behavior of the form.

You'll need to call `preventDefault()` on the form-submit event, and then submit the data manually after confirmation.

```
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4) {
            var confirmed = false;
            var result = xmlHttp.responseText;
            if (result == "clean")
                confirmed = true;
            else
                confirmed = confirm("RESULT="+result);

            if (confirmed) {
                var url = "addData.php";
                url=url+"?first="+encodeURIComponent(first);
                url=url+"&last="+encodeURIComponent(last);
                url=url+"&date="+encodeURIComponent(date);
                window.location = url;
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, when you're building your URL you should use encodeURIComponent.

```
    url=url+"?first="+encodeURIComponent(first);
    url=url+"&last="+encodeURIComponent(last);
    url=url+"&date="+encodeURIComponent(date);
```

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but no, I'm not performing an insertion via Ajax, I want to check for duplicates BEFORE submitting the form.  I know the `send()` is returning undefined, it was only setting to a variable for testing.

Comment: I'm a bit slow with ajax, so please bear with me, but isn't "the rest of his code" i.e. the alert and confirm, only happening when the onreadystatechange handler is called?

Comment: What he left out was the part where he was handling the form-submission event.  The event arrives, he issues the ajax request (which returns immediately) and then the regular form submission happens.  In all likely-hood, the form submits long before the confirmation ajax request is done.  You have to force these things to happen in sequence, either by ensuring a synchronous ajax request, or by overriding the default form-submission.

Comment: I edited my post to show how to perform the submission manually.  I'm going to post another solution, using synchronous requests.

Comment: there is no indication he is not submitting the form after checking the validate variable, but even if that is the case it still doesn't explain why the request, when it does return, is blank.